# java based CMS for NEWS site management

Tags: java

I am looking for a CMS which can manage NEWS site. It can also support video and audio data for news. I looked into some of the content management systems http://java-source.net/open-source/content-managment-systems but I am not able to find any suitable CMS for NEWS site.

I also need to integrate this CMS with mobile client (Android) for content display.

Kindly suggest any good CMS!

Thanks,
Raju

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to look outside of Java, Wordpress can work very well.

I hear If you're looking for Java, look at [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419968/best-open-source-java-cms). Look at [Liferay](http://www.liferay.com/), which seems to be very popular, and has some [news sites](http://www.liferay.com/web/ronald.sarayudej/blog/-/blogs/4656307/maximized?p_p_auth=h9r0QnZO) running on it.

I've also heard a bit of buzz about [Weceem](http://www.weceem.org), which runs on Grails.

Answer (score 0):

The referenced page included a link to magnolia and [magnolia](http://www.magnolia-cms.com/home.html) seems to have a news template. Android is almost always a challenge, because I guess that most CMS solutions heavily depend on big third-party libs (spring, hibernate, ...)

Comment: Is it possible to have some interface(Restful api) for communicating with CMS from Android client?